# add tag at specific div index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var element = document.getElementById("divname");      
var pagerHtml ='<a href="#" class="prev">&lt Prev</a>';         
for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++){ 
    pagerHtml += '<a href="#" class="'+ page>' + page + '</a>  ';  
}      
pagerHtml += '<a class="dotline" style="display:none;">........</a>';     
pagerHtml += '<a href="#" class="next"> Next &gt;</a>';    
element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;     
if(this.pages > 9){  
    for(var i=this.buffer;i<(this.pages-this.buffer);i++){   
         $("."+i+1)).hide();  
     }  
    }
```

I want to add class "dotline" so that when pages are hidden I would do `$(".dash").show();` and it would look like 1,2,.....,8,9,10.  any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're using inline code formatting. Paste the properly indented code, then select it and click the "Code Sample" button at the top.

Comment: This is a little too painful. ;o) Please stop editing, and reply to this comment to let me know you've stopped. I'll fix your code formatting for you, but I don't want my fix to be overwritten.

Comment: Looks like you've just about got it except that you're missing some string quotes, and I'm not sure at this point if those are missing from your actual code. Can you verify that this is an accurate representation of your code?

Comment: And `("."+i+1)).hide();` should be `$("."+i+1).hide();`

Comment: am sorry for the trouble Patrick dw :(

Comment: @stackover: It's no trouble. I'm just not sure if some of the defects in the code shown are there in your actual code, or if they're a result of your formatting efforts.

Comment: @PeeHaa yes i messed it up while presenting

Comment: Has this question been answered? Was it just the missing `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72LKN/1/).

I've updated the script as shown below.

```
var pages = 10;
var buffer = 3;

var pagerHtml = ['<a href="#" class="prev">&lt Prev</a>'];
for (var page = 1; page <= pages; page++){
    pagerHtml.push('<a href="#" class="'+ page + '">' + page + '</a>  ');  
}
pagerHtml.push('<a href="#" class="next"> Next &gt;</a>');    
$("#divname").append(pagerHtml.join(""));     

if(pages > 9){
    $("#divname a:gt(3):lt(" + (pages - 6) + ")").hide();
    $('<a class="dotline" >........</a>').insertAfter($("#divname a:eq(3)"));
}
```

Comment: @Arun: your answer is helpful..but with this am missing pages 3 to 12 from being added to the div. I was looking something like add all the pages plus dotline to div but based on number of pages show/hide pages and dotline.

Comment: When you deal with a lot of string concatenations, it is advisable to push the strings into a array and later join them using the join method because of performance issue.

Comment: insertAfter did the magic...i could modify whenever display has to change thanks Arun

Answer (score 0):

Can't edit post. However this is more what it should look like I think. Now what's the problem?

```
var element = document.getElementById("divname");      
var pagerHtml ='<a href="#" class="prev">&lt Prev</a>';         
for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++){ 
    pagerHtml += '<a href="#" class="'+ page> + page + '</a>';  
}      
pagerHtml += '<a class="dotline" style="display:none;">........</a>';   
pagerHtml += '<a href="#" class="next"> Next &gt;</a>';    
element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;     
if(this.pages > 9){
  for(var i=this.buffer;i<(this.pages-this.buffer);i++){   
    $("."+i+1).hide();  
  }  
}
```

Unfinished product, however you can play with / tweak this.

I've rewritten your code cause it didn't work. Lots of errors in it.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/tkwwZ/

Comment: Sry for posting this as answer. As it is not!

Comment: the above code results in smthing like this prev,1,2,9,10,...,next. But what i am working for is get prev,1,2,.....,9,10,next. does that make sense?

Comment: It is. Let try something out.

Comment: Check it out and refine / tweak it.

Comment: PeeHaa...i wonder if http://jsfiddle.net/tkwwZ/ will be active for long time..is it recommended that i post ur code in here ?